# Is this the best way to sync 100k records between org A and B?

Tags: apex, integration, sync

I need to find the best way to sync contacts between two org's and must be capable to support +100k records.

How can I Sketch this?

I suppose that need to use batch but cant run batch from trigger for 100k records, even if i can use batch right after the insert what happend if i try to update one of this records con the first org. I cant ensure that record will be created on the second org because batch runs async right?

How can I approuch this? any ideas? THANKS!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how/why a sync process for 100,000 records would be fired from a trigger?

Comment: You have some missing details here. When you say sync, what is your source of truth - A or B? You won't want two different orgs continuously overwriting each others data. What is your use case here? There could be multiple ways to address this, say S2S, ETL, nightly loads, etc. What options have you considered so far?

Comment: @DavidReed Im thinking in use trigger and queuable to process 100k

Comment: @JayantDas Org A its the source of truth, its just a sync from A to B, not B to A too. The requirement its to use Apex Code so im trying to figure out the best way to approuch before code. (cannot use SfToSf or conectors).

Comment: Is this a one time migration you are trying to perform or an ongoing integration?

Comment: Ongoing integration @BryanAnderson

Comment: Why can't you use PartnerNetworkRecordConnection ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a trigger, can you do this on a scheduled basis?

A design pattern for that would be having a batch class that runs on a predetermined schedule that would query the records for "integration" and perform the callout to your other org:

```
global class YourBatchClassvimplements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowCallouts
{
    //... Implement start(),execute(),finish() methods
}
```

For the actual integration mechanism, I would use the [Composite REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_update.htm) to perform the actual migration.

I would `JSON.serialize()` the sObject list coming into your `execute()` method and use that as the body of the Composite API call to insert/update records in your other org

Comment: Using schedule will take some time to insert all the records in org b and if i update one record on org A will also cause many problems =(

Comment: So do you want to send all records from Org A to B every time, or just ones that have updated since the last run (a very common use case)

Comment: Not every time but must be capable to sync 100k records

Comment: So what I have outlined will support 100k records. So that shouldn't be a concern in the solution I have provided

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. Left to me, I would take a hard look at the whole real-time, one-way sync architecture for so many records.

I am sure you've considered the queuable Apex limit and chaining jobs to make it all efficient. That can lead to the target system process time being a big variable when trying to process 100K records (~ 1+ transaction / second even in a 24-hour window , should be narrower for most businesses). But, I digress.

I would probably use a combination of the queueable Apex pattern with a debounce-like function that will add processing additional records to a future job rather than create another link in the chain. This should reduce the no. of call-outs during peak times.